# Xamarin Forms ListView Images Sometimes Displays, Sometimes Doesn't (UWP)

Tags: image, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a `ListView` in which I'm displaying the same image (`chevron_right.png`) in each of the rows.

On load, none of the images show.

However, when I navigate away from that page via `Navigation.PushAsync()` and then return back to the original page via `Navigation.PopAsync()`, the images display as they should.

Simplified version of my code:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Hello">
                    <Image Source="chevron_right.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="10">
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is occurring on Universal Windows Platform. Any help/incites/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What platform is this occurring on?

Comment: @Paul - Universal Windows Platform (I'll add to the post)

Comment: Coincidentally, I'm actually in the midst of investigating an issue that's incredibly similar to this on Windows 8.1. As an alternative method, do the icons show as expected when resizing the window?

Comment: @Paul they do not appear on resize. I've seen a post on the xamarin forums but it doesnt seem to pose a solution: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58567/issue-image-in-listviews-viewcell-on-uwp

Comment: @Paul I just got it to a place in which the images do appear on resize. Any luck with this weird issue? (but only on resizing the width of the window)

Comment: I faced this kind of situation on RangeObservable collection ItemSource usin LINQ, where due to LINQ it keeps refreshing and doesn't display images. If there is similar situation, try creating ItemSource List first and set.

Comment: I have the exact same issue in Xamarin.Forms and UWP. I think is a bug and if you resize the window, then the images will be displayed. In my case that happens.

Comment: @Paul, Jerrak0s - I found a logged bug, see my answer, maybe it'll help you if you're still stuck on this weird glitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a logged bug (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36097).

version 1.5.2.6469-pre1 is the last version where the issue does not occur.

Workaround that was functional for my purposes:
Place `Image` into a `<Grid>` and set the `ColumnDefinition Width = "Auto"` for the column that is containing said `Image`.

Hope this gets fixed soon!