# Xamarin Images sometimes not downloaded inside ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a ListView with two columns, the leftmost of which contains an `<Image>` like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image 
                            HeightRequest="130" 
                            Aspect="AspectFill" 
                            Source="{Binding DynamicOfferImage}" 
                            local:ImageBinding.URL="{Binding DynamicOfferURL}" 
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" 
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                            <Image.Aspect>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Aspect">
                                    <On Platform="iOS">AspectFit</On>
                                    <On Platform="Android">AspectFit</On>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Image.Aspect>
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Tapped="OnImageTapGestureRecognized"
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsRedeemed}" Margin="20" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                            <ContentView Padding="3" BackgroundColor="#d9534f">
                                <Label Text="{loc:_ S=LoginIsRedeemed}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#ffffff" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                            </ContentView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </AbsoluteLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                        <!-- Text here, irrelevant to question -->
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The `<Image>`'s `Source` property is bound to a URL of a JPEG image hosted on Amazon S3. The problem is *most of the time* these images are downloaded fine, however *sometimes* one image, or even all images, won't download (or won't display?)

This issue doesn't go away until the user *re-installs* the app. Even restarting the app doesn't count, it has to be an actual re-installation.

Below is a mockup of what this ends up looking like in some scenarios:
[image]

Any help much appreciated!

**NOTE**: This is not a duplicate of [Xamarin Forms ListView Images Sometimes Displays, Sometimes Doesn't (UWP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284247/xamarin-forms-listview-images-sometimes-displays-sometimes-doesnt-uwp), as that scenario described is different.

Comment: What is `local:ImageBinding.URL="{Binding DynamicOfferURL}" ` ? Might that be interfering with the image display? To me it seems there is either some kind of race condition such that if the downloading of the image loses the race, the image is not displayed, or the request to get the image from AWS is simply timing out sometimes. What you can try is to download and cache the images you need to a local file and then use that file as the source for the image. This would allow you to better observe the http request for the image and try again of the download fails.

Comment: `local:ImageBinding.URL` is just a custom binding I use to add an external link via tap gesture, bound from the view model. Every list item always has a bound URL for the purposes of linking to the website version of the displayed item. For this reason I doubt its related to this issue. I appreciate your suggestion and I may end up giving it a shot if there are no simpler solutions.

Comment: Why don't you use [ffimageloading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)?

Comment: after the image has been downloaded , do you update the imageView on the main thread ?

Comment: I'm not downloading the images and then setting it, I'm just setting the source of the image in the XAML to the URL of the image in S3. The images download and display automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking G.hakim's advice and decided to employ FFImageLoading (via NuGet package) for the images. It was pretty simple although I had to use a slightly older version for Xamarin.Android. Some weird linker error occurs with the latest version (2.4.4.859) and had to go back to 2.4.1. Either way it works really well and even adds a little animation to the images on Xamarin.iOS.

Here was my code before:

```
<Image 
    HeightRequest="130" 
    Aspect="AspectFill" 
    Source="{Binding ImageURL}" 
    local:ImageBinding.URL="{Binding LinkURL}" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <Image.Aspect>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Aspect">
            <On Platform="iOS">AspectFit</On>
            <On Platform="Android">AspectFit</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Image.Aspect>
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="OnImageTapGestureRecognized"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

In order to get FFImageLoading to work you have to add this to the root `<ContentPage>` element:

```
xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"
```

Then I was able to do this:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
    HeightRequest="130"
    DownsampleToViewSize="true" 
    Source="{Binding ImageURL}"
    local:ViewBinding.URL="{Binding LinkURL}">
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="OnViewTapGestureRecognized"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

In order for it to work with my `TapGestureRecognizer` I changed the `((Image)sender)` cast in the method to a `((View)sender)` cast because the `CachedImage` class in FFImageLoading doesn't actually inherit from `Image`, it inherits from `View`. Something to keep in mind if you have gestures or even custom bindings.

Aside from that it is very plug-and-play and I'm very happy with the outcome.

Comment: Better to use FFImageLoading